# iOS 9 Navigation Bar Tile Background

Tags: ios, swift, ios9

I have some problems in XCode. I tried to get my navigation bar colored which works perfectly but, the statusbar won't change its color too. I already searched, but nothing works for me.

I hope it is possible to do this without code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my take on this:

**First**, iOS gives only two kinds of status bar appearance - light or default.
   It is important to note as well that the system status bar no longer
   has any background color. When the API refers to
   `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent`, they mean white text on a clear
   background. `UIStatusBarStyleDefault` is black text on a clear
   background.

To set status bar white throughout the app:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent
```

To set status bar black throughout the app:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .default
```

**Second**, As a side note, in your `info.plist`, you can use `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `NO`if you want to set the above style at app level (inside your `AppDelegate`). Otherwise set this property to `YES` and implement following method in each your view controller to set different styles based on your needs:

```
override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
}
```

**Third**, To have a custom color on your status bar, you can add a `UIView` of desired colour just below the status bar like this:

```
UIView *addStatusBar = [[UIView alloc] init];
addStatusBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, 20);
addStatusBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor]]; //assign here your color 
[self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:addStatusBar];
```

**Fourth**, importantly, `UINavigationController` will alter the height of its `UINavigationBar` to either 44 points or 64 points based on following points:

- If the UINavigationController detects that the top of its view’s
  frame is visually contiguous with its UIWindow’s top, then it draws
  its navigation bar with a height of 64 points.
- If its view’s top is not contiguous with the UIWindow’s top (even if
  off by only one point), then it draws its navigation bar in the
  “traditional” way with a height of 44 points.